# Gradle Spring Boot: Add folder at root to jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

So I have a folder .ebextensions at the root of my spring boot project,and those files are not being included in my jar when I use "bootpackage" in my gradle plugin for intellij.I am deploying the jar On Amazon Web Services
How do I include these files in my jar?

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

 group = 'haughton.daniel'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}


ext {
springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR1'
}



 dependencies {
//compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4
compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure
//compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure', version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'


compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile ('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.30')

runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution:
Added this to my build.gradle

```
processResources {
from ('.ebextensions/') {
    into '.ebextensions'
}
}
```

Comment: This looks good but it's not at the root for me, it's in BOOT-INF\classes\ for me

Answer (score 2):

I added an *ebextensions* folder into source of my project, this contains the .ebextensions folder with nginx config:

Folder structure

[image]

I extended bootJar task:

```
bootJar {
   baseName = 'project'
   version = '1.0.0'
   from('ebextensions')
   //...
```

When I run **./gradlew cle ass bootJar**, then the unzipped *project-1.0.0.jar* contains:

- .ebextensions
- BOOT-INF
- META-INF
- org

I used Gradle 4.10.

The root cause was 413 Request Entity Too Large with ElasticBeanstalk.

Full content of proxy.conf:

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```